# Google+ style tiled photo gallery

Tags: javascript, photo-gallery

Has anyone seen a javascript library that will generate a photo gallery similar to the way Google+, and now Facebook, organizes photos where some are cropped, but the all seamlessly fill a space.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: A screenshot would be nice, given that many of us don't have any photos added to our Google+ accounts.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yeah, realized that, just did it.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot in understanding what you're looking for. Neat UI, I'll be watching this question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was doing some digging around and found this.  It's a bit different, but it still looks nice.  The only thing missing is the photo popping out.

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: +1 Nice find! You can probably do the pop out with a little bit of jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar and I've seen a couple now, this builds on jQuery: http://moewashere.com/jglance and this is really helpful guide: http://www.techbits.de/2011/10/25/building-a-google-plus-inspired-image-gallery/

Answer (score 0):

I've created a wordpress plugin that mimics the Google+ Gallery. The files in the js folder will be handy if you want to write a pure jquery version of this. Might do this myself later.

[Demo](http://bdwm.be/rgg/demo)
[Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/responsive-gallery-grid/)