# HTML/Javascript Tiling Images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Wondering if I have a dynamic list of image data, whether there's any libraries or techniques out there to tile the list of data. Keep in mind I don't know a priori how long the list is, but let's say that it is at least one (tile) row's worth of elements.

e.g. something like this
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google+ style tiled photo gallery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950842/google-style-tiled-photo-gallery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a grid, or pre-built table that has one row, and how ever many images acrross you want. Then when you get your images, get a count, and dynamically add rows, using the index of the image placing it into the index of the cell/td. Would be a good route, until you maybe find a library for it if there is one. Though, sometimes, if it isn't a huge "reinventing the wheel" type of snippet, there are some benefits to writing your own code for it. :)  Hopefully that helps.

By the way, jQuery Masonary, and Responsive Photo Grid are some libraries you could look into to. Here is a related post for you:[Mosaic Grid gallery with dynamic sized images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10930783/2762516)

Comment: One more great library to have a look at is Isotope - http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: I just posted one. A quick google search showed this on the return from a stack conversation. I just have never needed to use this style, so wasn't aware of a library off hand.

Comment: After looking into these, I think I might write one, and put my current project on hold. Though, I feel my current project would be very useful.  A problem that comes up a lot, so I don't know...  Post how the library works for you, to follow up if you don't mind!